# Java Message selector for getting group Message from websphere mq

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to Receive a Group Message from a **websphere mq 8 Queue Manager** within a Java mdb.
When getting the `LastMessageInGroup` I Receive a `jmsxgroupid` like **'ID:45fdea5589'** (`getStringProperty`) from the message.
When I'm trying to get the other Messages of this Group I'm Using a `messageconsumer` with a `messageselector` where I'm Adding exactly the `jmsxgroupid` with an additional `jmsxsequence` from above, but When calling the method `receiveNoWait` from the `messageConsumer` I receive a `Null` `BytesMessage`

The Funny thing is, when the `groupid` is Human readable String like '**20151019**' it Works.

So this is part of the Code.
We receive lastMessage in the method onMessage of our MDB.
We read the JMSXGroupID of this lastMessage with the method
    String gid = lastMessage.getStringProperty("JMSXGroupID").
Then we build a selector to get the other message(s) of this group like this:
    String strSelector = "JMSXGroupID='" + gid + "' AND JMSXGroupSeq=1";
    consumer = session.createConsumer(destIncoming, strSelector);
    bmCurrentMessage = (BytesMessage) consumer.receiveNoWait();
When the gid is like 'ID:8d74b544d5862f32156cbfe845077c02d18ba33ac51c06aa' we receive a null BytesMessage! The mq acts like the queue is empty.
When the gid is like '20151015081515' we receive the other messages of the group message!

Any Tips what I Should do different?

Thanks so far for Reading
Thomas

Comment: It may help if you can post your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after long time of analysing together with MQ experts from IBM we had to install a fix package offered by IBM to fix this problem. So there was obviously no problem with our code but some problem inside the IBM code of the MQ Server 8 we were using.

Now the problem is solved by installing the latest fix of IBM.

Thanks to all for reading and thinking about my problem!

Comment: Thomas, it is great that you your own answer to this question (also I know it was long ago), but could you update the answer to provide the APAR for the fix that IBM provided, that would help others in the future that run into the same problem to check if they are at a level that includes the fix you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the GroupID, just like the MessageID and CorrelationID, is not a string field. You say it works when it is a human readable string, which implies the times it is failing for you is when the GroupID is not human readable. This suggests you are not requesting the correct GroupID for the subsequent messages in the group because of the string processing you have done on it. Treat it as a byte string and not a character string.

Comment: Hi Morag, thank you for your answer. I use the group id I receive without change for looking for the other messages as 'ID:8d74...' I was understanding the documentation in a way that this representation is the one for a byte string?

Comment: From your question it seems you are doing string operations on it. Perhaps you can do as @Shashi requested and post your code, i.e. not just one or two lines of it in among your text, but a proper chunk of it.